# Hackerrank "Strings: Making Anagrams" Javascript Solution

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, bitwise

This is the [original problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-making-anagrams) :

> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains a single string, a.  The second line contains a
>   single string, b.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1<= |a|,|b| <= 10^4
>
> It is guaranteed that  and  consist of lowercase English alphabetic
>   letters (i.e.,  through ). Output Format
>
> Print a single integer denoting the number of characters you must
>   delete to make the two strings anagrams of each other.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> cde
>
> abc
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> 4
>
> **Explanation**
>
> We delete the following characters from our two strings to turn them
>   into anagrams of each other:
>
> Remove d and e from cde to get c. Remove a and b from abc to get c. We
>   must delete  characters to make both strings anagrams, so we print  on
>   a new line.

And this is the solution I've came up with using javascript. I've decided to use objects in order to avoid nested for loops which leads to O(M*N). I think my solution is O(M+N+O+P), however, I do believe there's a much better solution out there, and some more refactoring can be done to my code. Anyone?

There are some default I/O codes you may find in the original website

```
function main() {
  var a = readLine();
  var b = readLine();

  // Creating object with {"k": 5, "a": 2, "b": 1} for example
  var objA = countAlphabetFrequency(a);
  var objB = countAlphabetFrequency(b);

  var numOfDeletionsA = countNumberOfDeletions(objA,objB);
  var numOfDeletionsB = countNumberOfDeletions(objB,objA);

  console.log(numOfDeletionsA + numOfDeletionsB);
}

function countAlphabetFrequency (arrOfAlphabets){
    var resultObj = {}

    for (i = 0; i < arrOfAlphabets.length; i++) {
        if (resultObj[arrOfAlphabets[i]]) {
          resultObj[arrOfAlphabets[i]] += 1;
        } else {
          resultObj[arrOfAlphabets[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    return resultObj;
}

function countNumberOfDeletions (mainObj, referenceObj){
    var numOfDeletions = 0;

    for (var k in mainObj) {
        if (mainObj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
          if (mainObj[k] && referenceObj[k]) {
            // Alphabet k exists in both strings
            if (mainObj[k] > referenceObj[k]) {
              // Main string has more k than in reference string
              numOfDeletions += mainObj[k] - referenceObj[k];
              mainObj[k] = referenceObj[k];
            }
          } else {
            // Alphabet k only exists in Main string
            numOfDeletions += mainObj[k];
          }
        }
    }

    return numOfDeletions
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like your idea of counting character frequencies first. This allows you to count the required deletions in linear time.

Your code is readable, but readability can be improved by more semantic naming and leveraging modern JavaScript language features.

#### Naming:

Regarding the variable names `a`, `objA`, `mainObj`, `resultObj`, `arrOfAlphabets`: Those identifiers mainly include type information (`obj`, `arrOf`). But as a reader, I am more interested in the **role** of your variables instead of their type. So instead of `objA` I would prefer to read `frequenciesA` or even `freqA`. And instead of `arrOfAlphabets` I suggest the simpler `characters`.

#### For-loops:

First of all, you probably forgot to **declare** the local loop iterator in `for (i = 0; ...)`. Unfortunately, those omissions can introduce very hard to trace bugs as you now access and potentially share a global variable `i`.

Also, JavaScript arrays and strings implement the [iterable protocoll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol). This means you can iterate over them using a simpler **for-of** loop:

```
for (let char of characters) { ... }
```

This allows you to replace `arrOfAlphabets[i]` with the more readable `char`.

#### Default properties:

There is a pretty common technique used to handle default values of object properties. Replace

```
if (obj[arrOfAlphabets[i]]) {
  resultObj[char] += 1;
} else {
  resultObj[char] = 1;
}
```

with the shorter and idiomatic

```
resultObj[char] = (resultObj[char] || 0) + 1;
```

#### Enumerate object keys:

Instead of

```
for (var k in mainObj) {
    if (mainObj.hasOwnProperty(k)) { ... }
}
```

you can nowadays use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to write

```
for (let key of Object.keys(mainObj)) { ... }
```

#### Refactoring:

You probably noticed the redundancy in

```
var numOfDeletionsA = countNumberOfDeletions(objA,objB);
var numOfDeletionsB = countNumberOfDeletions(objB,objA);
console.log(numOfDeletionsA + numOfDeletionsB);
```

If you modify your `countAlphabetFrequency` function to increment frequencies for string `a` and decrement frequencies for string `b`, you can simply sum the absolute frequencies to get the number of required deletions.

If you combine that with a more descriptive approach by replacing for-loops with [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=control), you get a simpler implementation:

```js
// Count character deletions required to make 'a' and 'b' anagrams:
function count(a, b) {
  let freqs = {};
  a.split('').forEach(char => freqs[char] = (freqs[char] || 0) + 1); // increment
  b.split('').forEach(char => freqs[char] = (freqs[char] || 0) - 1); // decrement
  return Object.keys(freqs).reduce((sum, key) => sum + Math.abs(freqs[key]), 0);
}

// Example:
console.log(count('ilovea', 'challenge')); // 9
```

Comment: Highly comprehensive and insightful answer, thanks a lot @le_m ! : ) Yes your version of algorithm is definitely what I've been looking for, beautiful!

Comment: By the way for large cases forEach may have performance bounds? According to this article, "Array.ForEach is about 95% slower than for() in for each for Arrays in JavaScript." https://coderwall.com/p/kvzbpa/don-t-use-array-foreach-use-for-instead

Comment: The bounds are the same, but forEach's constant performance penalty is higher for now, compared to the highly optimised classical for-loop. The absolute difference however is marginal.